# Scheme - retrieve occurrences of a digit in a number

Tags: scheme

I'm working through the bert scheme exercises and having a tough time with this one:

Example : (n-occurences 544555 5) => 4

Any ideas how to have a count going?

I was thinking something like:

```
 (define (occurences d n)
   (if (equal? (remainder d 10) n)
       (add1 (occurences (quotient d 10) n))
       (occurences (quotient d 10) n)
       ))
```

So in an example such as 1223 2 it would:

1. Check if 3 is 2
2. Say no, and move on and call it again with 122 2
3. Check if 2 is 2
4. Say yes, and add 1 to the call with 12 2 (count is 1)
5. Check if 2 is 2.
6. Say yes, and add 1 to the call with 1 2 (count is 2)
7. Check if 1 is 2.
8. Say no and be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the base case of your recursion; you need to stop if d is 0. And you mixed up n and d a few times:

```
(define (occurences d n)
  (if (= 0 d)
      (if (= 0 n) 1 0)  ; base case
      (if (= (remainder d 10) n)
          (add1 (occurences (quotient d 10) n))
          (occurences (quotient d 10) n))))
```

Testing:

```
> (occurences 544555 5) 
4
```

The parameters (d and n) evolve as follows:

```
d=544555  n=5
d=54455  n=5
d=5445  n=5
d=544  n=5
d=54  n=5
d=5  n=5
d=0  n=5
```

Comment: This will fail in the edge case: `(occurences 0 0)` should return `1`, but it's returning `0`.